# Earth Engine- Find HUC boundary for each point

Tags: google-earth-engine, feature-collection

I am an EarthEngine noobie and I am trying to find the Hydrologic Unit code for each of my points in a table.

I have a table (featureCollection) full of observations and their Lat, Long coordinates, as well as a featureCollection of Hydrologic Unit Codes from USGS. Ideally, I would like to append properties from the HUC featureCollection to the observation table.

Here is what I have tried thus far:

```
//Read in HUC data and filter by geometry
var HUC = ee.FeatureCollection("USGS/WBD/2017/HUC10");
var studyHUC = HUC.filterBounds(myStudy_Geom);


/*Attempt to filter by one point to begin with. 
In reality, I would like to filter by a list of points as contained in a featureCollection
*/

var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point(-113.60517176189202,48.62284064317849)
var contains = function(feature){
  return ee.Algorithms.If(feature.contains(geometry));
}

//Set dropNulls to true because only one feature should contain the point
var containsTest = studyHUC.map(contains, true);
```

However, this map() returns an empty collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have the `condition` argument of ee.Algorithms.If(). Also mark the `trueValue` argument to return a value. And don't forget to cast the output to a feature:

```
 ee.Feature(ee.Algorithms.If(feature.contains(geometry), feature))
```

[link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e4526427401dd584859b79fcea3f49f3). Although you'd probably better use a spatial join. See an example in chapter 7 of [this page](https://colab.research.google.com/github/csaybar/EEwPython/blob/dev/6_Joins.ipynb#scrollTo=SLjQx1laglqK)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to implement the spatial join.